# What can cause yellowish horizontal bands when using a relatively high shutter speed?

Tags: color, shutter-speed, high-iso, fluorescent

I'm using a Canon 6D, using my Canon 50 mm f/1.8 lens.

I was taking pictures of my son using his "[youpala](http://static1.le-coin-des-mamans.fr/articles/5/35/5/@/381-le-youpala-pour-ou-contre-640x0-1.jpg)" (no idea how you say that in english :D) last night, in my kitchen, with only my ceiling lights as light sources.

Since he was moving fast, I was trying a setting that would provide me lot of speed. Here are my settings :

- Shutter priority mode, 1/200 s.
- ISO 25600
- Aperture around f/13 - f/14 (on the tests shots displayed below)
- Servo Mode to adjust quickly the focus
- Drive mode in burst
- Auto White Balance
- RAW

My pictures are pretty much all in focus, but, I ended having (on some pictures only) yellowish horizontal bands at random Y position... Sometimes on the bottom, sometimes in the middle, sometimes on the top and sometimes no bands and correct colors.

Here is an example of a 3 images burst shot with a slight move on the right... (using my wonderful kitchen cabinet, the result is pretty much the same with my kid) :

[image: Image 1/3]
[image: Image 2/3]
[image: Image 3/3]

Apart from a mysterious ghost apparition, could someone explain me what is happening here ?

Comment: Given than the OP mentions "bands" and is using a very high ISO, probabably no.

Comment: Sorry the term bands is badly chosen, it's indeed a dupplicate... Looks like my problem... I'll give it a read to be sure...

Comment: @PhilipKendall : Yes, indeed a dupplicate, it's exactely the same behavior I'm having... Thank you very much!